# Avoiding 0/0 in VBA

Tags: vba

I have this VBA Code:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
   
    For i = 1 To 13
        If Not IsNumeric(Controls("TextBox" & i).Value) And Controls("Textbox" & i) <> "" Then
        
            MsgBox "Error: Text found in TextBox" & i
            Controls("Textbox" & i).SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    For j = 2 To 5
        i = j * 2
        If Controls("Textbox" & i).Value = "" And Controls("Textbox" & i + 1) <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Missing Cost", vbExclamation, "Missing Information"
            Controls("Textbox" & i).SetFocus
            Exit Sub

        Else
            If Controls("Textbox" & i + 1).Value = "" And Controls("Textbox" & i) <> "" Then
                MsgBox "Missing Ratio", vbExclamation, "Missing Information"
                Controls("Textbox" & i + 1).SetFocus
                Exit Sub

            Else
                If Controls("Textbox" & i + 1).Value = "" And Controls("Textbox" & i) = "" Then
                    Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = 0
                    Controls("TextBox" & i + 1).Value = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    
    Next j
   
    If ws.Cells(9, 2) = "" Then
        row_number = 9
    Else
        row_number = ws.Range("B8").End(xlDown).Row + 1
        
    End If
    
    ws.Cells(row_number, 2) = Date
    ws.Cells(row_number, 3) = ComboBox1
    ws.Cells(row_number, 4) = ComboBox2
    ws.Cells(row_number, 5) = TextBox12 / 1
    ws.Cells(row_number, 6) = Label25 / 1
    ws.Cells(row_number, 8) = TextBox3 / 1
    ws.Cells(row_number, 9) = TextBox13 / 1
    ws.Cells(row_number, 10) = ((TextBox12 / 100) * TextBox2) * (TextBox3 / 1000000) - ((TextBox13 / 100) * TextBox2) * (TextBox3 / 1000000)
    ws.Cells(row_number, 12) = ((TextBox4 * TextBox5) + (TextBox6 * TextBox7) + (TextBox8 * TextBox9) + (TextBox10 * TextBox11)) / ((TextBox5 / 1) + (TextBox7 / 1) + (TextBox9 / 1) + (TextBox11 / 1))
    ws.Cells(row_number, 13) = (((TextBox12 / 100) * TextBox2) - ((TextBox13 / 100) * TextBox2)) * (((TextBox4 * TextBox5) + (TextBox6 * TextBox7) + (TextBox8 * TextBox9) + (TextBox10 * TextBox11)) / ((TextBox5 / 1) + (TextBox7 / 1) + (TextBox15 / 1) + (TextBox17 / 1))) / 1000000
    ws.Cells(row_number, 15) = ws.Cells(row_number, 10) / 1 - ws.Cells(row_number, 13) / 1
    ws.Cells(row_number, 16) = ws.Cells(row_number, 15) * Label25
```

However, as it stands, `w.Cells(row_number, 12)` is a calculation where 0 divides by 0. How do I avoid this? Especially when TextBox4 to 11 can be left blank?

Answer (score 2):

You identified this line as the issue:

```
ws.Cells(row_number, 12) = ((TextBox4 * TextBox5) + (TextBox6 * TextBox7) + (TextBox8 * TextBox9) + (TextBox10 * TextBox11)) / ((TextBox5 / 1) + (TextBox7 / 1) + (TextBox9 / 1) + (TextBox11 / 1))
```

The fix is to do it in multiple steps:

```
Dim denominator
denominator = (TextBox5 / 1) + (TextBox7 / 1) + (TextBox9 / 1) + (TextBox11 / 1)
If denominator <> 0 Then
    ws.Cells(row_number, 12) = ((TextBox4 * TextBox5) + (TextBox6 * TextBox7) + (TextBox8 * TextBox9) + (TextBox10 * TextBox11)) / denominator
Else

End If
```

What you put in that `Else` block is up to you (maybe set the cell to a blank empty value).